# Add custom language to content language

Tags: joomla-3.4, language, content

I'm creating a multilangue joomla site with English and Faroese.

Faroese isn't in the language list, but my site is just made up of articles and menu's that I'm creating at my own, so I don't need to download anything but I want to add Faroese and English to my Content Languages. And have 2 flags up in the right top lettings users change in between languages, just like normal.

My problem is that Faroese isn't in the list when creating a new content language. How can I manually add it or somehow get it available?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hope this can help you.

You need to create a Languaje Content entry for your language.

Go to Extensions->Language Manage -> Content

And create a new record as shown in the picture

[image]

In order to get the flag I created a new gif file fo.gif and uploaded to
 **media/mod_languages/images**

Here is it if you need it

[image]

Comment: Thanks! so all I needed was to add that image to that folder to get it to work :)

Comment: Your welcome. It seems so!!

Comment: Now that i have set the site fully up, i don't get the option for Faroese in my language switcher module? I'm thinking it has something to do with that I haven't installed Faroese?